# Conditions for $(I-x A)$ to be contractive for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

- Real parts of eigenvalues of matrix $A$ must have same sign for $I-xA$ to be contractive for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$
- Suppose no 0 eigenvalues. Is it also a sufficient condition?

Comment: what does $\mathbb{R}(\lambda(A))$  mean?

Comment: real part of eigs of $A$, updated

Comment: $  \Re  $    testing  this symbol for real part is  \Re   and imaginary  $\Im$   or \Im   which is ugly and soes not remind me of the letter I  or the letter m

Comment: Do you assume that $A$ is a matrix ? Otherwise $A$ may not have eigenvalues.

Comment: Also need the real parts to be non-zero. So same sign + non zero is sufficient

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The question is for matrices. How would I go about proving it?

Comment: The conclusion is certainly true for normal matrices, i.e such that $A$ commutes with $A^*.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion is not true in general. Consider the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 2\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $I-xA$ is not contractive for any $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}.$ Indeed
$$I-xA=\begin{pmatrix} 1-x& -2x\\
0 & 1-x
\end{pmatrix}$$
Hence $I-xA$ is not contractive for $x<0$ and $x>{1\over 2}.$ We can restrict to $0<x\le {1\over 2}.$
We have
$$B_x:=(I-xA)^*(I-xA)=\begin{pmatrix}(1-x)^2 & -2x(1-x)\\
-2x(1-x) & 4x^2+(1-x)^2
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $\det B_x=(1-x)^4$ and ${\rm tr}\, B_x=2(1-x)^2+4x^2.$ The characteristic equation is
$$\lambda^2-2[(1-x)^2+2x^2]\,\lambda +(1-x)^4=0$$
One of the roots is equal
$$\displaylines{\lambda=1 - 2 x + 3 x^2 + 2x\sqrt{1 - 2 x + 2 x^2}\\ \ge 1-2x+3x^2+2x(1-x)=1+x^2>1}$$
Thus $B_x$ is not contractive, so neither is $I-xA.$

The conclusion is true if $A$ is a normal matrix. In that case $A$ is unitarily equivalent to the diagonal matrix $D$ with the eigenvalues of $A$ on the main diagonal. We have $\|I-xA\|=\|I-xD\|.$ The matrix $I-xD$ is contractive if and only if $|1-x\lambda|\le 1$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A.$ Assume the real part of $\lambda$ is positive for every $\lambda.$ Hence $\lambda=u+iv,$ where $u>0.$
Then $$|1-x\lambda|^2=(1-xu)^2+x^2v^2=1-2ux+(u^2+v^2)x^2$$
Thus $|1-x\lambda|<1$ for $0<x<2u/(u^2+v^2).$ Therefore $x$ should satisfy $$0<x <\min_{\lambda} {2{\rm Re }\,\lambda\over |\lambda|^2}$$

Similar analysis can be made if $u<0$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda.$

Comment: Are you sure it's not contractive? Using x=1/3 gives a map with eigenvalues 2/3, 2/3

Comment: The magnitude of the eigenvalues is not sufficient. For example the matrix with eigenvalues equal $0$ does not need to be contractive.

Comment: For $x=1/3$ the norm of $I-xA$ is equal $\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{5}}/3>1$

Comment: Ah, I see. I've been thinking of linear maps with stable fixed point, it seems "contractive" is too strict of a requirement for this, good example

Comment: posted follow-up here -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4489595/conditions-for-i-x-ak-to-be-contractive-for-some-x-in-mathbbr-k-ge-1