# Conditions for $I-x A$ to be a convergent matrix for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

I'm looking for interpretable necessary/sufficient conditions on $A$ which guarantee that $(I-x A)$ is a [convergent matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_matrix) for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$

For instance, $A$ normal with non-zero eigenvalues having real parts of same sign seems [sufficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4489267/998). What about non-normal $A$?

For instance, let $A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)$, we can visualize trajectories of $\left(I-x  \left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)\right)^k$ below.

$A$ satisfies this condition because of spectral radius condition, $\rho(I-xA)<1$ for any $0<x<2$

[image]

Following [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.05289) it seems the example above is provably convergent because this map is contractive under coordinate change $y=Px$ with

$$P=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{2 \sqrt{\frac{29}{3}}}{3} & -\frac{4}{\sqrt{87}} \\
 0 & \frac{10}{\sqrt{87}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

[image]

Coordinate transformation $P$ under which $x=Ax$ becomes contractive for any stable $A$ can be obtained by solving the following (comes from discrete Lyapunov equation)

$$P^T P = T\left(\frac{T^{-1}A^{-T}U}{\lambda(A)-\lambda(A^{-1})^T}\right)U^{-1}$$

with
$$\begin{align}
T&=\text{columns of right eigenvectors of } A\\
U&=\text{columns of left eigenvectors of } A^{-1}\\
\lambda&=\text{column vector of eigenvalues}\\
a-b&=\text{subtraction with numpy broadcasting rules}\\
a/b&=\text{componentwise (Hadamard) division}
\end{align}
$$

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-contractivity.nb)

Comment: Is $x$ fixed, or we just want that there exist one for which $(I-xA)^k$ is contractive?

Comment: The latter, just need some $x,k$. This feels like a discrete version of "Lyapunov stability". For continuous time systems, the requirement would be that $A$ is either positive stable or negative stable, looking for a proof of something similar in this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{v_k\}$ be some orthonormal eigen-vectors and $\{\sigma_k\}$ the corresponding eigen-values of $A$, then for $n\geq 1$, $(I-xA)^n v_k=(I-xA)^{n-1}(v_k-x\sigma_k v_k)=(1-x\sigma_k )(I-xA)^{n-1}v_k=(1-x\sigma_k)^n v_k$. Now one can argue that since any vector $y$ is a combination of the $v_k$, then $(I-xA)^n y\to 0$ for all $y$ is true when it is true for the eigen-vectors, indeed if $y=\sum_{k} y_k v_k$, then $(I-xA)^n y=\sum_k y_k(1-x\sigma_k)^n v_k$.

In order for it to be true, you need to find a $x$ such that $|1-x\sigma_k|<1$ for all $k$. In particular $\min_x\max_k |1-x\sigma_k|<1$ iff there exists $x$ such that $I-xA$ is convergent.

Now this is equivalent to $\min_x\max_k |1-x\sigma_k|^2<1$ which in turn is equivalent to $\min_x\max_k (1-x2\mathrm{Re}\{\sigma_k\} +x^2|\sigma_k^2|)<1$ which can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
0>\min_x\max_k x(|\sigma_k|^2x-2\mathrm{Re}\{\sigma_k\})
\end{align*}
In particular this will hold if and only if all of the (unordered) intervals $\left]0,2\frac{\mathrm{Re}\{\sigma_k\}}{|\sigma_k|^2} \right[$ intersect, meaning that $\mathrm{Re}\{ \sigma_k \}$ should have the same sign for all $k$ (and be non $0$).

Comment: $\rho(I-xA)<1$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for convergence. Here I'm interested in conditions on $A$ which guarantee existance of $x$ that makes $\rho(I-xA)<1$

Comment: I rewrote a bit, removing the bad part. I think after few simulation that the necessary and sufficient condition is that $0<\sigma_1$ or $\sigma_m <0$, in otherwords all eigen values have the same sign (and are non zero).

Comment: Does it mean they have to be real valued? Or are complex valued eigs allowed?

Comment: I think now my answer should be fine, essentially you need all real value of eigen-value to have the same (strict) sign.

Comment: Why do you assume that $\{x_k\}$ are orthonormal eigenvectors of $A$? What is $\{v_k\}$? Is $x$ a scalar or a vector?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was horrible. Now it should be better, $x$ is a real as in the question, the vector is named $y$ (and doesn't really matter).

Comment: @P.Quinton orthonormal eigenvectors are for normal matrices only, I'm interested in non-normal (which any random matrix is bound to be). You may enjoy these slides by Mark Embers -- http://www2.mpi-magdeburg.mpg.de/mpcsc/events/trogir/slides/psa_slides.pdf

Comment: looks like section 4.3.1 gives essentially same result as yours, without relying on orthonormal eigenvectors -- https://math.unice.fr/~frapetti/CorsoF/cours3.pdf

Comment: Interesting indeed.

Comment: You don't need orthogonality because x=Ax converges to the largest eigenvector, so just apply eigenvalue condition to that value

Comment: Oh right, makes sense. I guess it converges to the eigenspace of the largest (absolute) eigen value, right ?